# Getting same page on every URL/Route in Laravel8

Tags: laravel

I'm using default laravel auth , I have multiple routes with prefix group but when I use other routes/urls but giving the same page on every route which is View page the product

you can see my route

```
Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('products')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [ProductsController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/{code}', [ProductsController::class,'view_product'])->name('products.view_product');
});
```

On this below route giving the product_view page which I can't understand why is giving

```
Route::get('/test_route', , function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

```
+--------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
----+------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                      | Name                        | Action
    | Middleware                               |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
----+------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                 | generated::suiIeX6oHZWSnSP1 | Closure
    | api                                      |
|        |          |                          |                             |
    | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum |
|        | GET|HEAD | sanctum/csrf-cookie      | generated::WKOquUKjM8nfHvKl | Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController@s
how | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD | products              | generated::IucNuoXqqYtZPi70 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@index
    | web                                      |                                     |
|        | GET|HEAD | {code}                   | products.view_product         | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@view_product
    | web                                      |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
----+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `Route::get('/test_route', , function () {` - You've got an extra `, ` in there, `Route::get('/test_route', function () { ... });`

Comment: I have remove but still same error

Comment: Can you please declare `test_route` after auth routes?

Comment: Can't recreate this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jPpE.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y283B.png. If I navigate to `/product`, I get `On /`, if I navigate to `/product/test`, I get `On /{code}`, and if I navigate to `/test_route`, I get `On test_route`. You might have a wildcard route somewhere else in there that is messing with your routes, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69470474/edit) and include all relevant `route/web.php` code.

Comment: @TimLewis same here. @spiral can you please share the result of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @tim-lewis I have updated my question with a route list. Thanks

Comment: It is not taking `/products` prefix - https://prnt.sc/1v1z7id @Spiral

Comment: Dear @TimLewis I have removed all routes and paste which you have added in the comment but giving the ``{code}`` route whereas I have removed all. What is that

Comment: Yes @Vdpawar Dear you are right. but I have removed all routes and test with same [https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jPpE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jPpE.png) but giving ``{code}`` what is that

Comment: Don't use my routes verbatim; I don't have a Production Controller locally, so I had to use `function () { dd(...); }` instead. Maybe try with `Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function (){ // your / and /{code} routes here; });`

Comment: Dear for test i have used your routes with anonymous function in the route but why is giving same route which I have removed.